# Docker compose and volumes with Apache

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am attempting to set up a project using Docker and Docker compose on Mac OS. I have however run into some problems trying to mount volumes.

My ubuntu:latest image works fine when I copy my main site folder in my Dockerfile:

```
COPY www /var/www/site
COPY apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Although this works I need to be able to able to reflect changes to my code without having to rebuild. So I thought it would be easy just to use volumes in my docker-compose.yml file (removing the first copy line above in Dockerfile):

```
web:
    volumes:
        - ../www:/var/www/site
```

My docker-compose.yml file resides in the /build folder, all project files in /www.

No error messages when building or running docker-compose up but Docker does not seem to find its way. The only thing that shows up when I go to my home url is an empty "Index of /" Apache page.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does it work if you use absolute path to `www`?

Comment: No, it did not but you got me thinking in the right direction so thanks anyway :) Apparently it did not work when it was placed in a folder in the Applications folder for some reason. When moving the project outside it worked but now I have anoher issue with permissions in the mounted directory where I need to have a couple of writable subdirectories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, it looks like you were running into the fact that the Docker Machine running on VirtualBox is only mounting the `/Users` folder into the VM and thus anything outside your `/Users` folder on the Mac wouldn't be able to be mounted into a container.

This is called out about halfway down on https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/:

> If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, your Docker daemon
>   has only limited access to your OS X or Windows filesystem. Docker
>   Machine tries to auto-share your /Users (OS X) or C:\Users (Windows)
>   directory.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Now I only have to be able to make folders in the mounted directory from docker-compose.yml writable which seems tricky also. I've tried usermod and chmod to no avail yet.